# Android - How to know clicked widget id to put in int

Tags: android, widget, android-pendingintent

I have this Code:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int i=0; i< appWidgetIds.length; i++){
        if (first == false){
        lista.addAll(FullList.list);
            first=true;
    }
        views = new RemoteViews (context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        iii = r.nextInt(1007);
        text = lista.get(iii);
        txti[i] = text;

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv1, text);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("N", txti[WidgetID_HERE]);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
    }
```

So What I need is when someone clicks the widget on field **(WidgetID_HERE)** to be placed the clicked widget id..
Why?
All Widgets contain random text, and when user clicks on widget, MainActivity needs to display only text from that widget nothing else..

Comment: Do you need the id of a view clicked?

Comment: maybe that, everything I need is to pass the text from widget to activity..
But when I have more widgets, so if someone click at one widget, how I will know which text to pass at the activity..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String clickedButton = getResources()
                    .getResourceName(v.getId());
        }
```

Comment: I need at `txti[WidgetID_HERE])` so if the first one read `txti[1]` if second one than read `txti[2]` etc...
SO I thing if is first widget than is 0 and I will get `txti[0]`

Comment: What is txti? where is it declared?

Comment: String[] txti = new String[15];